# create a linux user with create files and write permissions without sudo access

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, non-root-user, useradd

I want to create a user in such a way that it can create a file and update the contents of the file.

```
useradd username
```

Now for sudo, we can create username and linking to sudo like below:

```
useradd username sudo
```

But I dont want to give sudo access. Without sudo access, I am unable to create files and update files.

Comment: If you don't want to give `sudo` privilege, then don't give `sudo` privilege (don't add user to group, `sudo`). All users can create, write, read files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what files you want, you can create a new group (`/etc/group`) and make the file writable (and the directory containing it if you want the user to create new files) by that group (e.g., `chgrp <groupname> <file>; chmod g+w <file>`